# Error when running VBA macro on different computers

Tags: regex, vba, excel, properties, runtime-error

I have written a macro in VBA that is working perfectly for my file. The problem is that when I am running this macro (of the same file) on a different computer, I get the following error:

> Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

... when executing `.Item(0).Value` in the following code:

```
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-zA-Zá-ùÁ-Ù])(\d+)"
    With .Execute(strText)
        strRes = .Item(0).Value
```

I suspect that maybe something is dependent on the specific Workbook or file path (although I cannot find the dependency), but I cannot resolve this weird behavior.

Comment: What application (Word, Excel, ...), and what versions, on each machine?

Comment: Based on [error description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445484(v=vs.60).aspx) the most common reason of above error is that: index exceeds the range...

Comment: "of the same file" - what's the value of `strRes` when it blows up?

Answer (score 4):

It practically means that the string *strText* has no match with the regular expression. As mentioned in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfy6y4h1(v=vs.84).aspx):

> `Execute` returns an empty Matches Collection if no match is found.

So this means `.Item(0)` does not exist and is an invalid reference:

```
strRes = .Item(0).Value
```

To solve this, test that there is at least one element in the collection using the `Count` property:

```
With .Execute(strText)
    strRes = "" ' Default value
    If .Count > 0 Then strRes = .Item(0).Value
```

Depending on what your code does with *strRes*, you might want take a different action when *Count* is 0. The above code tries to continue with the empty string, but maybe you want to exit a function, or display a message to the user, or still something else...